# Ajax loaded content div class is not applied

Tags: ajax, class, html

I have a page that has a few divs connected in a flowchart via JS-Graph.It. When you click one of the divs, I want it to 1) generate text in a special div 2) generate a popup via click functions attached to the two classes "block" and "channel" in each div. This works when the page is static.

When I add ajax so on click of a button and add more divs, only one of the two classes appears in the HTML source. "Channel" is no longer visible and the function to generate a pop-up on click of a channel class div does not work anymore...

AJAX call:

```
$("#trace").bind('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
    var button2 = $('#combo').val();
    if(button2 == 'default') {
        var trans = 'Default View';
    }
    if(button2 == 'abc') {
        var trans = 'abc';
    }
    $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
        url: 'serverside.php', // JQuery loads serverside.php
        data: 'button2=' + $('#combo').val(), // Send value of the clicked button
        dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
        success: function(data) // Variable data constains the data we get from serverside
        {
            JSGraphIt.delCanvas('mainCanvas');
            $('.test').html('<h1>' + trans + '</h1>'); // Clear #content div
            $('#mainCanvas').html(''); // Clear #content div
            $('#mainCanvas').append(data);
            JSGraphIt.initPageObjects();
        }
    });
    return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 

}, this));
```

DIV class: (works in index.php but not transactions.php)

```
// Boxes
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<div id="'.$row['id'].'_block" class="block channel" style="background:';
```

Functions:

```
$(document).on('click', '.block', $.proxy(function(event) {
    var input = $(event.target).attr('id');
    var lines = input.split('_');
    var button = lines[0];
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'srv.php', 
        data: 'button=' + button,
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#content').html('');
            $('#content').append(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}, this)); // End Application Details

$(".channel").click(function () {
        alert('channel');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about registering with pages, I'm not sure exactly how it works. The fix should be to change your channel click function to be the same as your first and use the .on('click') option.

found some related reading material. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I was playing around and ended up trying that. I think it's taking me in the right direction..